# How to find the ports that is being used by a process in golang or in general?

Tags: shell, go, port, pid

My binary takes a port parameter and starts a http server. If pass a 0 to the -port, it will find a free port and start on it.

After this, how do I find which port is this if I have the command object with me and can get the process id? I am trying to write my application in golang. I am also curious how this is done in general.

Comment: If you want this information from within your program, just use the `Addr()` method on the [`net.Listener`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listener). If you want it outside, you could either do something like `netstat` or you could have your program save the address/port being used somewhere (just like how many daemon write a pidfile).

Answer (score 5):

It's OS specific, but on linux you can do

`netstat -npl`

that will list which programs are listening on which ports

If you just want to print it out from your app, you can use the alternative form of starting the http server by creating your own tcp listener and then call http.Serve

example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    lsnr, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":0")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println("Listening on:", lsnr.Addr())
    err = http.Serve(lsnr, nil)
    fmt.Println("Server exited with:", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

outputs:

```
Listening on: [::]:53939
```